# how to resolve following error?

Tags: annotations, sapui5

I have followed [cards for overview pages using annotations](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/10/fiori-overview-page-ovp-creating-list-table-and-stack-card/%20%22overview%20pages) 
this link to create a stack card, but I'm getting following error.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'sap/ovp/cards/charts/stack/Component.js' from /resources/sap/ovp/cards/charts/stack/Component.js: 404 - Not Found

Every bit of code is same as given in tutorial. I think my annotation file is incorrect. Please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use the following in manifest:

```
"template": "sap.ovp.cards.stack"
```

instead of

```
  "template": "sap.ovp.cards.charts.stack"
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solves the problem